# RestSharp DownloadData out of memory exception in .net app

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory, restsharp

I have facing `System.OutOfMemoryException` which is occurring in case I try to download some files (26mb) while the memory available is larger than the download file as many times (1gb). Any idea.

Project details:
.Net 7 / C# / RestSharp

Place of the exception:

```cs
RestClient client= new RestClient(BaseUrlApi, c => c.MaxTimeout = 60 * 1000);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(path);
var file = client.DownloadData(request); // System.OutOfMemoryException
```

```
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at RestSharp.Extensions.StreamExtensions.<ReadAsBytes>d__0.MoveNext()
   at RestSharp.RestClientExtensions.<DownloadDataAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
   at RestSharp.RestClientExtensions.<DownloadDataAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
   at RestSharp.AsyncHelpers.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`1.<<RunSync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
   at RestSharp.AsyncHelpers.CustomSynchronizationContext.<<Run>g__PostCallback|7_0>d.MoveNext()
   at RestSharp.AsyncHelpers.CustomSynchronizationContext.Run()
   at RestSharp.AsyncHelpers.RunSync(Func`1 task)
   at RestSharp.AsyncHelpers.RunSync[T](Func`1 task)
   at RestSharp.RestClientSyncExtensions.DownloadData(RestClient client, RestRequest request)
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You should really use `DownloadStreamAsync` instead as it is asynchronous and non-blocking, and it will return you the response stream, which you can then dump to a file or anything else.

It's mentioned in the [documentation](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#downloading-binary-data).